# How do I use an external USB keyboard?

Tags: usb, keyboard, usb-peripherals, external-keyboard

My tablet's running Android 4.0.3, and I'm trying to use an external keyboard with it. My tablet isn't detecting the keyboard, but it works when I plug it into my computer. This keyboard uses a normal USB output to connect, but my tablet uses MicroUSB, so I bought an adapter. How do I get this keyboard to work?

Comment: See also this question for more info on testing Host mode and getting it working [How can I determine if my device has USB Host Mode (OTG) support?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/)

Answer (score 2):

If your tablet doesn't provide a USB host port, you'll need an [USB OTG adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) to connect your keyboard. There are many cheap USB OTG adapters on eBay and other electronics shops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help at all, but I had a problem with the Shift Key not working when I had a USB keyboard plugged into my Android phone and I found a solution.  Maybe the solution I found for my problem will fix your problem as well.  If not, I do apologize.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 Android phone.  I purchased a USB external physical keyboard that can connect with my Windows computers and my Android devices (via micro USB).  The keyboard worked fine when I plugged it into my Windows computers.  The keyboard worked pretty well Android phone, except for the fact that the Shift Key didn't do anything when I held it down and pressed other keys (to capitalize letters, type symbols found above the number keys, etc.).  I tried a lot of stuff to get the Shift Key to work on my USB keyboard when I had it plugged into my phone. I couldn't get the Shift Key to work when I used the stock Google/Android keyboard app, the Samsung Keyboard app, or the SwiftKey Keyboard app. After a lot of trial and error with apps and settings (and a lot of frustration), I FINALLY came across an app  that DOES solve the Shift key problem: The "Go Keyboard" app on the Google Play app store.

After I installed this app and set it as the default keyboard app on my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S5), the Shift key  worked just fine when I used it while it was plugged into my Android phone (allowing me to capitalize letters and  type symbols above the number keys).

I hope this works for you, too!